# Solving a differential equation with substitution

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I have this equation, $y''=2y(y')^3$ here. To solve this I first need to substitute another variable since it's second order. I think using $y'=u$ is a good choice here since it covers  all cases. What do I do next to solve this? I manipulated the equation to make it into $u'u=2yu^3$.

Comment: Not sure why the ODE being second order implies you need to do a substitution. If this is an assigned problem in a course you're taking, is that in the wording of the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you switch variables, you end with
$$x''+2y=0$$ which seems to be pleasant and which could easily be inversed ... providing the conditions.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution

$$
\begin{align}
0&=2y\cdot\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^{3}-\frac{d^{2}y}{dx^{2}}\\
\\
&=2y\cdot\frac{dy}{dx}-\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^{-2}\cdot\frac{d^{2}y}{dx^{2}}\\
\\
&=\frac{d}{dx}\left[y^{2}+\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^{-1}\right]\\
\\
\\
C_{1}&=y^{2}+\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^{-1}\\
&\leftrightarrow\\
x&=-\frac{1}{3}\cdot y^{3}+C_{1}y+C_{2}
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 1):

There are several good solutions here, but I thought I'd submit yet another, which seems more direct:
\begin{align*}
y''&=2y(y')^3\\
\frac{y''}{(y')^2}&=2yy'\\
\int\frac{y''}{(y')^2}\,dx&=\int 2yy'\,dx\\
-\frac{1}{y'}&=y^2+C_1,
\end{align*}
at which point you can separate variables.