First order ode with tricky IC. How to obtain same solution as computer?
$$
y'=\sin \left(y\right)
$$
With initial conditions
\begin{align*}
y \left(0\right) = \pi
\end{align*}
Integrating both sides gives
\begin{align*}
\int \frac{1}{\sin \left(y \right)}d y &= \int d x\\\\
\ln \left(\csc \left(y \right)-\cot \left(y \right)\right) &= x +c_{1} \tag{1}
\end{align*}
I used Maple to integrate $\frac{1}{\sin y}$ Now raising both sides to exponential gives
\begin{align*}
\csc \left(y \right)-\cot \left(y \right) &= {\mathrm e}^{x +c_{1}}
\end{align*}
Which can be written as
\begin{align*}
\csc \left(y \right)-\cot \left(y \right) &= c_{2} {\mathrm e}^{x}
\end{align*}
Now the problem is in solving for the constant of integration. Since $\csc(y)$ gives $\frac{1}{0}$ when $y=\pi$. Similar problems with $\cot(y)$. So this approach does not work.
Solving for $y$ first from (1) did not help either. Maple gave arctan expression with same problem when trying to find constant of integration from it.
Both Maple and Mathematica give this final solution
$$
           y(x)=\pi
$$
The question is, how to obtain this solution? The issue is in solving for the constant of integration since this is just quadrature problem. The integration is correct.
Any tricks to use to find $c_2$ ? Note that this is not singular solution since this ode is linear in $y'$ hence has no singular solution. This solution came from the general solution after finding the constant of integration from initial condition.

The problem is much simpler if you switch variables
$$\frac 1{x'}=\sin(y) \quad \implies \quad x=c_1 +\log \left(\tan
   \left(\frac{y}{2}\right)\right)$$ that is to say
$$y(x)=2 \cot ^{-1}\left(c_1\, e^{-x}\right)$$
$$y(0)=2 \cot ^{-1}\left(c_1\right)=\pi\quad \implies \quad c_1=0\quad \implies \quad y(x)=\pi$$

Yes, thanks. This is much simpler. Will use this trick again I am sure.

@Nasser. This switch allows to solve many problems. Have a look at this one  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4269056/solving-a-differential-equation-with-substitution/4269073#4269073

For a separable DE where the general solution is of the form $F(x) = G(y) + c$, and there's a particular solution that is constant, you're likely to get this sort of problem.  The particular solution can't really satisfy the equation of the general solution, because the right side would have to be constant but the left side is not.
Instead of trying to get it from the general solution, you can find constant solutions directly: look for the values of $y$ that make $\sin(y) = 0$.

Preliminary minor remark: you forgot absolute values in two of your equations. It should be $\ln\color{red}|{\csc y-\cot y}\color{red}|=x+c_1$, and $\color{red}|{\csc y-\cot y}\color{red}|={\mathrm e}^{x+c_1}$ or equivalently $\csc y-\cot y=\color\red\pm{\mathrm e}^{x+c_1}$. The next equation, $\csc y-\cot y=c_2{\mathrm e}^x$, is then correct, but with $c_2<0$ allowed.
Your calculations prove explicitely that if a maximal solution $(I,y)$  of $y'=\sin y$ is such that $\sin y(x_0)\ne0$ for some $x_0\in I$, then $I=\Bbb R$ and $\sin y$ never vanishes on $I$. Therefore, if $\sin y(x_0)=0$ for some $x_0\in I$ then $y'=\sin y=0$ everywhere, i.e. $y$ is constant.
However, you can obtain this conclusion without any calculation, using the Picard–Lindelöf theorem , which guarantees the uniqueness of the maximal solution for your ODE with initial condition: since the constant function $y(x)=\pi$ is a solution, it is the solution.
